# Substring failing in shell script

Tags: shell-script

```
for file in *.csv
do
  split -n 5 -d -a 1  "$file" "$file"
  for each in $(seq -w 2 3)
  do
        echo $each
        filestem="$file$each"
        len_filestem=${#filestem}
        subs=substr(len_filestem,3,4)
        echo $subs
        echo $filestem
  #awk '{filename = "wrd." int((NR-1)/10000) ".txt"; print >> filename}' $file--$each
  awk -v filestem= "{$filestem}" '{filename = substr(filestem,3,5};  print >> filename}' $filestem

  done
done
```

Im trying to find the substring of a string but my script is failing in substr(len_filestem,3,4)

Comment: Its failing in this line ---subs=substr(len_filestem,3,4)

Comment: `substr()` is an awk command, not an executable.

Comment: You probably want `subs=${len_filesystem:3:4}`

Comment: Is there any good reason to talk about an error message but not adding it to the question?

Answer (score 1):

The error is the space after the `=`:

```
-v filestem= "{$filestem}"
```